# timeout command in docker container not working

Tags: docker, timeout

I ran the following command:

```
docker run python:3.8-alpine /bin/sh -c "timeout 1s sleep 5"
```

I expected it to terminate after 1 second, but it took 5 seconds to terminate instead.

If I enter the container and execute the command like below, it terminates correctly after 1 second:

```
docker run -it python:3.8-alpine /bin/sh
timeout 1s sleep 5
```

Why did the first command behave differently than expected?

Answer (score 6):

In Docker container this process `/bin/sh -c "timeout 1s sleep 5"` runs as `PID 1`.

The `timeout` command uses the `SIGTERM` to stop a process.

According to this [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/):

> A process running as PID 1 inside a container is treated specially by Linux: it ignores any signal with the default action. As a result, the process will not terminate on SIGINT or SIGTERM unless it is coded to do so.

And according to this [link](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html):

> The only signals that can be sent to process ID 1, the init
> process, are those for which init has explicitly installed signal
> handlers.  This is done to assure the system is not brought down
> accidentally.

You must tell Docker to run the container with `--init` option (runs an init process):

```
docker run --init python:3.8-alpine /bin/sh -c "timeout 1s sleep 5"
```

Comment: Worked for Mac too, btw.

Answer (score 3):

you can also kill the `PID 1` with `trap` and kill the process.
Trap allows you to catch signals and execute code when they occur.

```
docker run python:3.8-alpine /bin/sh -c "trap "exit" SIGINT SIGTERM && timeout 1s sleep 5"
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also do this:

```
timeout -s KILL 1s docker run python:3.8-alpine /bin/sh -c "sleep 5"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the correct question.
when you run

```
/bin/sh -c "timeout 1s sleep 5"
```

you said to execute the **sleep** command and wait for 1 second to execute it. also when you use the **-c** option you said to **sh** execute this command as a parameter of **sh**. but without the **-c** option it would like to execute from a file and said no such file or directory to execute so you thought your timeout executed but it's not true.

Example:
on your terminal type the following commands to catch it:

```
1. #bash "echo hi"
```

it said no such file or directory

```
2. #bash -c "echo hi"
```

it was executed correctly.

I hope I was able to convey my meaning.

Comment: That's not the case here as the command wasn't quoted when the shell received it so it executed it as expected, as evidenced by the fact that it took 5 seconds to complete.  Good point - just not applicable in this case.